# mysql count records by subquery on same table

Tags: mysql, join

my problem is that i am joining 4 tables by left join so i cant use group by rather than sub query.
but **how do i get the count of main table based on specific column**
any tips .
Is it possible.
Thanks in advance

I have tried this way.

```
    SELECT * ,sql_1.trans
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table b ON condition
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT count(*) trans,dentist_id as did3 FROM table1  
    GROUP BY dentist_id
    ) sql_1 ON did3=a.dentist_id
    WHERE a.current_tab='pack'
```

Comment: Am I understanding correctly: You want to get the count of rows before the GROUP BY? And ignoring the possible duplicate rows due to the LEFT JOINS?

Comment: No,i want to count how many entries of dentist_id in table1 table that mean count duplicate entry